# Ajax Chosen plugin affect only one dropdown?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I currently have a ajax script that dynamically builds two select boxes enabled with the Chosen plugin found here: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen.  I've narrowed down that Line 9 is what enables the Chosen Plugin and from what I can tell the scripts builds the markup for the selects dynamically.  How do I split this building of the dynamic select markup so that the first select is NOT enabled with the Chosen plugin?

```
$(function(){

    var questions = $('#questions');

    function refreshSelects(){
        var selects = questions.find('select');

        // Improve the selects with the Chosen plugin
        selects.chosen({ disable_search_threshold: true });

        // Listen for changes
        selects.unbind('change').bind('change',function(){

            // The selected option
            var selected = $(this).find('option').eq(this.selectedIndex);
            // Look up the data-connection attribute
            var connection = selected.data('connection');


            // Removing the li containers that follow (if any)
            selected.closest('#questions li').nextAll().remove();

            if(connection){
                fetchSelect(connection);
            }

        });
    }

    var working = false;

    function fetchSelect(val){

        if(working){
            return false;
        }
        working = true;

        $.getJSON('citibank.php',{key:val},function(r){

            var connection, options = '';

            switch (r.type) {
                case 'select':
                    $.each(r.items,function(k,v){
                        connection = '';
                        if(v){
                            connection = 'data-connection="'+v+'"';
                        }

                        options+= '<option value="'+k+'" '+connection+'>'+k+'</option>';
                    });

                    if(r.defaultText){

                        // The chose plugin requires that we add an empty option
                        // element if we want to display a "Please choose" text

                        options = '<option></option>'+options;
                    }

                    // Building the markup for the select section

                    $('<li>\
                        <p>'+r.title+'</p>\
                        <select data-placeholder="'+r.defaultText+'">\
                            '+ options +'\
                        </select>\
                        <span class="divider"></span>\
                    </li>').appendTo(questions);

                    refreshSelects();
                    break;
                case 'html':
                    $(r.html).appendTo(questions);
                    break;
            }

            working = false;
        });

    }

    $('#preloader').ajaxStart(function(){
        $(this).show();
    }).ajaxStop(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

    // Initially load the product select
    fetchSelect('callTypeSelect');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).

```
selects.filter(":not(:first)").chosen({ disable_search_threshold: true });
```

or

```
selects.not(":first").chosen({ disable_search_threshold: true });
```

Comment: Close...that works but it "breaks" the chain select with the second select box?  Any way to avoid that?

Comment: is it possible to do a similar treatment of not and first on where chosen is initialized?  selects.chosen({ disable_search_threshold: true });  @Alexander

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco, "chain select"?

Comment: @ Alexander, the first and the second select boxes are "chained together" based on the selection of the first select box.  This "breaks" that functionality.

Comment: selects.not(":first").chosen({ disable_search_threshold: true }); worked perfectly!!